# Regex to check IE version

Tags: regex

I need to block IE versions upto 6. for user agent strings I wrote a regex which blocks IE 4 5 and 6. But I came across this string:

`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; TheFreeDictionary.com; FunWebProducts; FBSMTWB; GTB6; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; InfoPath.2)`

In this string, there is MISE 6.0 mentioned so my regex blocks it. However it is actually IE 8 browser. So how can I construct a regex that scans for IE which is above 6 and if IE 4-5-6 appears again in the string it will ignore it.

Comment: what language are you using for this? There may be a better solution than regex. There may also be a better solution than browser version detection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not look for occurrences of `MSIE 6.0` to block, detect the version as a floating point number with code like this: (You didn't specify a language so I give the example in PHP)

```
preg_match( '/MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/', $userAgent, $matches );
$version = float( $matches[1] );
if( $version <= 6.0 ) {
    // BLOCK
}
```

The code above will use the first occurrence of `MSIE x.x` to detect the version and will ignore the rest.

**UPDATE:**

In Javascript:

```
var re = new RegExp('/MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[.0-9]{0,})/g');
if(re.exec(userString) != null) {
   version = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
}
```

Comment: In Javascript I get no match in IE9 unless I pass the expression to `new RegExp` *without* the single quotes (i.e. not as a string), in which case I can just say `var re = /MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[.0-9]{0,})/g;`

Comment: NOTE: IE 11 doesn't have `MSIE` in it's user-agent string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have heard a zillion times that looking into `userAgent` -- the process called "browser sniffing" -- does not work reliably. Browsers can and do change that string whenever and however they want. You can save yourself days of failure and endless lame explanations by forgetting about `userAgent` and instead using [**object detection**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html), which requires no pointless calls to `regex` and yields a reliable result. (Read more about [**browser detection**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html).)

You might want to consider using browser detection methods other than sniffing.

HTH

Comment: ohh..to be frank, I am quite new to scenarios of browser detection and didn't know this. I will keep in mind what you said, thanks

Comment: In argument to that. One reason you would want to use browser detection is. A bug crops up in IE9 and the way to fix it is change the line height. But only in IE9. Granted you could use html IE detector tags.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reasonably limiting yourself to just one regexp ? Can you create a *set* of regexps to determine pass/fail patterns ?

Comment: after a lot of testing, this scenario came up. that this particular user agent string had multiple tokens of IE versions in it. So for now, I want to block this particular type of user agent string. and i would like to get it done in one regex. I tried to do as you asked. But I have been instructed to minimize regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Browser Sniffing gets a bad rap, and sometimes it's justified.. detecting new browsers using UA sniffing isn't a good idea. But if you are trying to detect IE5,6,7 there is a VERY good chance that it's not going to be an issue.

```
preg_match_all('/(MSIE\s?)(6|7)[\.0-9]{0,}/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
```

Works for me